# reinstall all FreeBSD packages with pkg_add, pkg_info

Tags: freebsd, openbsd

In OpenBSD, I have the possibility to take a snapshot with all my installed packages, with

```
pkg_info -m > output.txt
```

and then move this file to a different server and on this new server run a:

```
pkg_add -lz output.txt
```

and all packages will be re-installed. checking the man page from FreeBSD pkg_info and pkg_add I didn't find it. Is there any recipe to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what is written in [the manual](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/packages-using.html): use `pkg_info` to see what you have installed, output that to a file, then you can do something like (assuming you are using bash or a POSIX compliant shell) `pkg_add -r $(cat mylist.txt)`.

Comment: hi @schaiba. It didn't work as you suggested. Instead I had to remove the version first. The OpenBSD version from pkg_add is smarter. I did something like:  pkg_add -r $(cat mylist.txt | cut -f1 -d\-)